# Undeclared port verilog error

Tags: verilog

I'm trying to do fixed point division in verilog and I encounter  two errors related to an undeclared port(r2 and c2). I don't know why this happens because at c and q it works.Can you help me ? Thanks.

```
module tema1(a,b,q,c,r);

    input[7:0] a;  
    input[7:0] b; 

    output[15:0] q; 
    reg[15:0] q;
    output[7:0] r2;
    output[7:0] c;
    output[7:0] c2;
    output[7:0] r;
reg[7:0] r2;
    reg[7:0] c;
    reg[7:0] c2;
    reg[7:0] r;

    always @(*)
        begin


        c = 8'b00000000;
        r = a;
        c2 = 8'b00000000;

        repeat (30)
                    begin
                        if (r >= b )
                            begin
                        c = c + 1;
                        r = r - b;
                            end
                    end

        $display("c=%d", c);
        $display("r=%d",r);



                r = r * 10;
                r2 = r;
                repeat (30)
                    begin
                        if (r2 >= b  )
                            begin
                            c2 = c2 + 1;
                        r2= r2 - b;
                            end
                    q[8:7]=c2;

                    end


                r = r * 10;
                r2 = r;
                repeat (30)
                    begin
                        if (r2 >= b  )
                            begin
                            c2 = c2 + 1;
                        r2= r2 - b;
                            end
                        q[7:6]=c2;

                    end


                r = r * 10;
                r2 = r;
                repeat (30)
                    begin
                        if (r2 >= b  )
                            begin
                            c2 = c2 + 1;
                        r2= r2 - b;
                            end
                        q[6:5]=c2;

                    end


                r = r * 10;
                r2 = r;
                repeat (30)
                    begin
                        if (r2 >= b  )
                            begin
                            c2 = c2 + 1;
                        r2= r2 - b;
                            end
                        q[5:4]=c2;

                    end


                r = r * 10;
                r2 = r;
                repeat (30)
                    begin
                        if (r2 >= b  )
                            begin
                            c2 = c2 + 1;
                        r2= r2 - b;
                            end
                        q[4:3]=c2;

                    end

                r = r * 10;
                r2 = r;
                repeat (30)
                    begin
                        if (r2 >= b  )
                            begin
                            c2 = c2 + 1;
                        r2= r2 - b;
                            end
                         q[3:2]=c2;

                    end


                r = r * 10;
                r2 = r;
                repeat (30)
                    begin
                        if (r2 >= b  )
                            begin
                            c2 = c2 + 1;
                        r2= r2 - b;
                            end
                         q[2:1]=c2;

                    end


                r = r * 10;
                r2 = r;
                repeat (30)
                    begin
                        if (r2 >= b  )
                            begin
                            c2 = c2 + 1;
                        r2= r2 - b;
                            end
                    q[1:0]=c2;

                    end






end

endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you declared `r2` and `c2` as outputs, but they do not appear in the port list.  The syntax you are using is from Verilog-1995 where you might have to define a port up to 3 times (1 position in the port list, direction, and data type). Please use the updated Syntax from Verilog-2001 (and now SystemVerilog)

```
module tema1(
        input[7:0] a,b,
        output reg [15:0] q,
        output reg [7:0] c, r
        );
// internal 
        reg[7:0] c2, r2;
```